# C language 2d array fill diagonal with numbers from 1 to n

Tags: c

I have a 2d array filled with 0's and i'm trying to fill the main diagonal with numbers from 1 to n, this is the main code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
    
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int m, n, i, j;
    printf("Number of rows and columns:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n][n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            a[i][j] = rand() % 1;
    printf("The matrix is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf(" \n ");
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf(" %d\t ", a[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

What I've tried to do is to fill the diagonal manually, but that's not what I want to do. I want to make it fill itself automatically. I need to do it without using any functions.

Comment: Diagonal is located at `a[i][i]` , so a single loop is sufficient. But in your program it is not filled with zeros as you claim.

Comment: What do you mean by `rand()%1`? This is not zero.

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef This expression is always equal to 0.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are wrong. The array is filled with zeroes.

Comment: `rand()%1` is a strange way to produce 0. Why not just use `0`?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, ok. It is rather cryptic way to zero the array though.

Comment: @EugeneSh. you're discussing something that's not about the point, when de-facto the array is filled with zero.

Comment: @Vlad It is about the point that the code, especially not directly relevant to the question, should be *clear* to  the readers in order not to distract them from the point.

Comment: Anyway, are you asking about how to set the diagonal in the zeroed-ot array, or how to incorporate the setting into the array which is zeroing it out? These are two different things.

Comment: `a[i][j] = i == j ? rand() % n + 1 : 0;` is one way to put random numbers from 1 to n in the diagonal positions and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: @EugeneSh. are we there to discuss how to fill an array with zeros or how to fill the diagonal with numbers from 1 to n, where n is the dumber of the rows and columns?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Just now I have found a bug of Stackoverflow. Your comment to Vlad has flied to me.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, you are Vlad too :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "fill itself automatically". Could you clarify?

Comment: @Vlad This is addressed in my first comment. Just iterate over `a[i][i]`.

Comment: Also not sure what you mean by filling the diagonal with numbers 1 to n. Do you mean use each number from 1 to n only once and (since random numbers seem to be involved in your code) in a random order?

Comment: @IanAbbott meaning that it is not filled manually, but using the code for it to fit itself. 
By the way, thank your for the suggestion that you gave earlier, but it doesn't work properly, for me at least, saying that, i mean : if i introduce n=5, it goes for the main diagonal something like that: 2 6 2 3 4 (this are the numbers in the diagonal)

Comment: @IanAbbott yup, i mean in ascending order from 1 to n

Comment: @Vlad So `a[i][j] = i == j ? i + 1 : 0;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = ((i == j) * (i + 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to add this part after you fill the matrix with zeros.

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    arr[i][i] = i + 1;
```